# jQuery: How can I valide input field during typing?

Tags: jquery, validation

My current code is like this and is click-based, not typing-based:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#btn_send').on('click', function() {

content_input_username = $('#input_username').val();

$.post('system/check_username.php',
        {
            'content_input_username':content_input_username
        },
        function(responseText)
        {
            if(responseText == 'false')
            {
                $('#username_info').html('username available');
            }

            if(responseText != 'false' && responseText != 'sql_error')
            {
                $('#username_info').html('user name not available');
            }



        }
    );

}); // /button-click

});
```

How can I achieve that the input field is being **permanently** validated during typing? What do I need to change?

Comment: Could you add the check after a keyup event?

Comment: From a usability perspective, it's rarely necessary or desirable to restrict what characters one is typing as one is typing them. Users may interpret that as a broken keyboard. Furthermore, one could cut-and-paste text into the field, and you'd need to validate it on `change` anyway.

Comment: input event is more suited for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

2 things here.

First you should change the click event to input or change (more on this later) event.

Since you are doing an ajax request, is not ideal for everykeystroke so 'change' is a good alternative, but, it will only fire when you lose focus on the input, which can make it rather annoying.

'input' to the rescue. The input event will fires for every keystroke, but you must take some considerations since if I type "bart" it will just fired 4 request with a race condition and that's totally bad. You should throttle validation so, you do the request if user stopped typing for lets say, 3 secs.

Also note that 'input' is not available on older browsers, but you can add change also for older browsers like : `.on('change input')`

`notes on: keyup` this event will fire even you use the cursor to move right left or replacing a letter with the same letter while input will only fire if the input changes. So I will stay away of `keyup` event.

Comment: thanx for your answer. unfortunately I cannot really follow. could you please write down the entire correct code? that would be great

Comment: This is what I meant in my original answer Max. I've edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: check out this detailed blog post of Remy Sharp. http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

Comment: @Bart i have used the code below from your link, but I get the error message "debounce is not deifned". what could be wrong? $('input.username').keypress(debounce(function (event) {
  // do the Ajax request
}, 250));

Comment: you need to define the debounce function (first paragraph of code)

Comment: Take the event handler out of `$(document).ready` and replace it with `$(document).on('change input', '#input_username', function()`.

Comment: @NobleUplift that would create an unnecessary event delegation that will check of all changes elements inside document.

Comment: But it works. Can you add an efficient event delegation to your answer for the OP? If it works, I will concede.

Comment: @NobleUplift no need, this will do it: $('#input_username').on('change input', function(){});

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391349/904344)'s solution (go upvote!). I wanted the OP to have a complete code example, and to direct attention away from the keyup event, which we both thought was the wrong way to go.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_username').on('change input', debounce(function() {
        content_input_username = $('#input_username').val();

        $.post('system/check_username.php',
            {
                'content_input_username':content_input_username
            },
            function(responseText)
            {
                if(responseText == 'false')
                {
                    $('#username_info').html('username available');
                }

                if(responseText != 'false' && responseText != 'sql_error')
                {
                    $('#username_info').html('user name not available');
                }



            }
        );

    }, 250));
});
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418999/904344) is my source for using 'change input'.

Comment: The `change` event doesn't fire until you click or tab away from the text field.

Comment: @NobleUplift The change event will not fire until it focus out from that field.

Comment: Good catch! I'll edit that into my answer ant point towards someone else.

Comment: -1 You cannot delegate an element's event to itself. Without seeing the OP's markup, you cannot tell whether there is an `<input />` element inside of an element with id `input_username`.

Comment: That's such an asinine, semantic cop out to give a -1. The OP prefixed the id with "input_", and you're seriously going to argue it's not an input tag?

Comment: You obviously don't understand how event delegation works. I have no doubt that `$('#input_username')` is an input tag. You code is delegating the change event to an `<input />` element inside of the `$('#input_username')` element. Delegation works by applying the event to a parent element and letting child events bubble up. The correct delegation without further clarification from the OP would be `$(document).on('change', '#input_username', function () { ... });`. In this case, the change event fired from the `#input_username` element and bubbled up to the document would be run here...

Comment: I apologize. If you check my source, you'll see that I wrote the line wrong from what I was reading. The event handler that I wrote is working perfectly on my local.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was completely my bad. I panicked with -2 on my answer and then saved it without thinking. Then I had to go AFK and couldn't immediately fix it.

Comment: +1 after the edits. I think this answer should be accepted for completeness and future reading. Mind removing the old solution to avoid confusion?

Comment: Will do! It will live on in my heart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyup event handler

```
$('#input_username').on("keyup", function(){
    //do your validation here.
    content_input_username = $('#input_username').val();

    $.post('system/check_username.php',
    {
        'content_input_username':content_input_username
    },
    function(responseText)
    {
        if(responseText == 'false')
        {
            $('#username_info').html('username available');
        }

        if(responseText != 'false' && responseText != 'sql_error')
        {
            $('#username_info').html('user name not available');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: if 'bar' is false and 'bart' is true. I can get into a race condition where I type 'bart' and get 'user name not available'. Throttle should be used.

Comment: @Bart I think, in this case keyup event will help. because it will fire in every keyup occured. if you type "bar" and also when "bart" it will show validation with current value.

Comment: because you are doing a request (post) for every keystroke you can't assume that the 'bart' response will come after the 'bar' one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition. Also is not a good practice and a waste of resources to make a request for every keystroke.

Comment: @Bart I liked your answer. As my assumption we can do anything according to need. Because his question was to validate on typing. No offence but that's the point.

Comment: You are right, you answers the OP question, even if it can fails or is not a good practice or whatever, he asked how to do it on typing and you solution does exactly that. I'm used to recommend quality code or spot flaws in this case scenarios but I think that's something i need to fix on myself. thanks for the feedback :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="validate()">

$(document).ready(function()
{

function validate() {

content_input_username = $('#input_username').val();

$.post('system/check_username.php',
        {
            'content_input_username':content_input_username
        },
        function(responseText)
        {
            if(responseText == 'false')
            {
                $('#username_info').html('username available');
            }

            if(responseText != 'false' && responseText != 'sql_error')
            {
                $('#username_info').html('user name not available');
            }



        }
    );

}

});
```

Comment: using your code, the console tells me with every click that "validate is not defined"

Comment: Yes, where is validate called from?

Comment: `validate()` is fired on keypress ^^^

Comment: @MaxNagler : validate method will be fired on keypress event in the text field.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was only reading the JavaScript and completely ignored the tag.