# QML property temporary value without completely breaking binding

Tags: qt, qml, property-binding

In QML (at least until version 5.6<sup>1</sup>), property bindings are broken once a new value is assigned in a JavaScript context:

```
Item {
    property bool sourceBool: <some changing value e.g. from C++ code>
    property bool boundBool: sourceBool

    function reassignBool() {
        boundBool = true;
    }
}
```

Once `reassignBool` is called, `boundBool` will be `true` regardless of the state of `sourceBool`.

I would like to be able to assign a temporary value to a property that will not break the original binding; the temporary value would persist until any of the `NOTIFY` signals associated with the original binding are triggered, at which point the bound property would again reflect the value computed by the binding.

As an example use-case, suppose I have a button that I don't want the user to be able to press twice in a row, and which is enabled or disabled according to some set of rules:

```
MyButton {
    id: onceOnlyButton
    // Suppose the QML type `MyButton` provides a boolean property
    // called `enabled` that greys out the button and prevents it from
    // being clicked when `false`.
    enabled: <condition1> && <scondition2>
    onClicked: {
        <schedule some asynchronous work>
    }
}
```

Suppose that, when the button is clicked, `<condition1>` will *eventually* become `false`, so that the button would *eventually* be disabled appropriately--but not *immediately*.

So I would like to do something like the following:

```
....
onClicked: {
    enabled = false
    <schedule some asynchronous work>
    enabled = Qt.binding(function() {
        return <condition1> && <condition2>
    }
}
```

... but of course as soon as I re-establish the binding, since `condition1` hasn't *yet* become `false`, `enabled` will become `true` again.

I suppose I could create some kind of `Connections` object that would connect the `NOTIFY` signal(s) associated with `<condition1>` to a handler that would invoke `Qt.binding`, then....delete the `Connections` object, I suppose. But this seems pretty complicated and inelegant.

Is there any way to ensure that `enabled` is set to `false` *immediately*, then re-bound to the `NOTIFY` signals for `<condition1>` and `<condition2>` as soon as any of those signals are emitted?

<sup>1</sup> I'm not entirely sure how assignments affect bindings in 5.7, but I know that [assigning a value to a property does not automatically break the binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840642/1858225). So this might just work automagically out-of-the-box in 5.7.

Answer (score 4):

This should be fairly straightfoward to achieve using QML `Binding` type, which is great for temporarily overriding a binding without destroying it (and it has been around since before version 5.6!)

You will need a variable or property which you can use in the `when` property of the Binding type. In the example below I have used `timer.running` because the asynchronous work scheduled here is just a timer.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool condition1: true
    property bool condition2: true

    Button {
        id: onceOnlyButton

        enabled: condition1 && condition2

        Binding on enabled {
            when: timer.running
            value: false
        }

        onClicked: {
            timer.start()
        }
        text: "onceOnlyButton"
    }

    // stuff below is just for demonstration
    Button {
        anchors.left: onceOnlyButton.right
        text: "toggle Condition1\n(to prove binding still intact)"
        onClicked: condition1 = !condition1
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 2000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: condition1 = false
    }
}
```

If you don't have a variable you can use to establish whether the asynchronous work is still going on (like my `timer.running`) then you will need to create one, as below property `forceButtonDisable`. This makes it look more complicated, so lets wrap it up inside a new re-usable component:

### OnceOnlyButton.qml ##

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    id: control
    property alias text: button.text
    property bool enabled
    property bool forceButtonDisable: false

    signal clicked()

    onEnabledChanged: forceButtonDisable = false

    width: button.implicitWidth
    height: button.implicitHeight

    Button {
        id: button

        width: control.width
        height: control.height
        enabled: control.enabled

        Binding on enabled {
            when: control.forceButtonDisable
            value: false
        }

        onClicked: {
            control.forceButtonDisable = true
            control.clicked()
        }
    }
}
```

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool condition1: true
    property bool condition2: true

    // once clicked, the button is temporarily disabled until original binding expression results in a different value
    OnceOnlyButton {
        id: onceOnlyButton

        text: "onceOnlyButton"
        enabled: condition1 && condition2
        onClicked: timer.start()
    }

    // stuff below is just for demonstration
    Button {
        anchors.left: onceOnlyButton.right
        text: "toggle Condition1\n(to prove binding still intact)"
        onClicked: condition1 = !condition1
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 2000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: condition1 = false
    }
}
```