# how to make checkbox check in php echo if one is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting array input from multiple checkboxes, but I want two different types of value set (emails combined and name combined)

```
echo '<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="select_dept[]" value="'.$email.'" id=id1['.$i.'] onclick="if(document.getElementById(id1['.$i.']).checked){ document.getElementById(id2['.$i.']).checked=true"} >
<input type="checkbox" name="select_dept_name[]" value="'.$name.'" id=id2['.$i.']>'
.$id.' &nbsp '.$name.' &nbsp '.$mobno;
```

Comment: and this code is in loop with $i;

Answer (score 0):

[Binding two checkboxes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478997/binding-two-checkboxes-together)

THIS thing solves the problem
echo '
                                    
                                    ';