# jQuery change function loop for multiple select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 8 select fields numbered 1 to 8. I have the code below working to show/hide the recurring div numbered 1 to 8 but can't figure out how to put it in a loop to prevent duplicate script. Should I use the for loop or each command for this? any help is appreciated. Below is an example of what currently works for the first 2 select boxes.

```
jQuery(function() {
    id = 1;
    jQuery('#leveltype' + id).change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "recurring") {
            jQuery('#recurring' + id).show();
        } else {
            jQuery('#recurring' + id).hide();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function() {
    x = 2;
    jQuery('#leveltype' + x).change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "recurring") {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).show();
        } else {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Try to setup your functions to work on change event, using .on:

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

There you should check 'change' event.

Then second, as for me, you should consider connecting your functions not on the ids, but on class names, or any other not unique attributes. For example, you have 8 selects with ids id1, id2, id3 ..., but they have class "mySelect", then you can connect jQuery to them using class selector:

```
jQuery('.mySelect')...
```

That should work. Try it.

Example from [SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418963/jquery-onchange-function-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-inputs)

Comment: Don't link to w3schools, they are a truly bad resource. There are better resources, the jQuery documentation for examples.

Comment: Yes, just visit w3fools.com

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`attribute starts`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with selector,

```
jQuery('[id^=leveltype]').change(function(){
  jQuery('#recurring' + (this.id).replace("leveltype",""))
      .toggle(this.value=="recurring");
});
```

And the better approach would be using a `class selector` at this context. Also using `data-attribute` will be handy for us at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I asume you have tried the following?:

```
for(x=1; x<9; x++){
    jQuery('#leveltype' + x).change(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "recurring") {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).show();
        } else {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

This won't work because the change function is fired after the for has been looped, so the x will be 8 all the time.
To solve this you need to get x inside the change function.
For this you can use the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function or save the x inside the DOM.

DOM example:

```
for(x=1; x<9; x++){
    jQuery('#leveltype' + x).data("num", x);

    jQuery('#leveltype' + x).change(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "recurring") {
             jQuery('#recurring' + jQuery(this).data("num")).show();
        } else {
            jQuery('#recurring' + jQuery(this).data("num")).hide();
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks! II had tried the first version you listed and failed as you said. got your modification to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use each with a callback, in my opinion is a better choice to avoid closure issues:

```
var myCallback = function(index, value) {
        value.change(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).val() == "recurring") {
                jQuery('#recurring' + index).show();
            } else {
                jQuery('#recurring' + index).hide();
            }
        });


};

var myArray = $('#leveltype');
jQuery.each(myArray, myCallback (index, value) );
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary and goes against the usage pattern of jQuery. Almost all jQuery functions affect all selected elements, there is no need to call `.each` just to attach an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

use class 'leveltype' instead, with attribute data-id="x":

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.leveltype').change(function(){
        var t = jQuery(this), x = t.attr('data-id');
        if (t.val() == "recurring") {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).show();
        } else {
            jQuery('#recurring' + x).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: They are all in a leveltype class. Is this better than the for loop which is listed above and I've gotten to work?

Comment: Actually the for loop way is also works, but I rarely see people put the event listener in the for loop. In fact using class, that you are letting jQuery to loop for you instead of writing your own.