# How to check and uncheck a checkbox and then create a column in the last column of the table

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Night all.
I have a question here. I have a table that created by `javascript` function I made. In that table contain a `checkbox` in each row and the `thead` has the `checkbox` too. I have separate the id's of the `checkbox` for the each row use id `mycheckbox` and for the `thead` use id `mycheckbox1`.

OK now to the problem.
I have to try to make all of my checkbox can be checked with the checkbox in the `thead` with id `mycheckbox1`. I have try many code that I have found. But no one working. And I try make a fiddle with a table that I manually created with HTML and I can check all the texboxt and it work fine like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/29fnt79f/1/

But when I try to use that in my page it can't work
this is the code for the table that I have created

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
  if ($('#files').val()== "")
  {
   alert("Anda Harus Memasukkan File Terlebih Dahulu");
  }
  else{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#files').parse({
   config: {
    delimiter: "",
    skipEmptyLines: false,
    complete: displayHTMLTable,
   },
   before: function(file, inputElem)
   {
    //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
   },
   error: function(err, file)
   {
    //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
   },
   complete: function()
   {
    //console.log("Done with all files");
   }
  });
  }
    });
 
 function displayHTMLTable(results) {
    var table = "<table class='table table-bordered' width='90%'>";
    var data = results.data;
    var size = -1;
 var check = 7;
    var header = "<thead><tr>";
    header+= "<th width='120'>Kode Material</th>";
    header+= "<th width='140'>Storage Location</th>";
    header+= "<th width='130'>Movement Type</th>";
    header+= "<th width='130'>Id Indentifier</th>";
    header+= "<th width='120'>Date Input</th>";
    header+= "<th width='80'>Netto</th>";
    header+= "<th width='50'>Unit</th>"; 
 header+= "<th width='80'>Payroll</th>"; 
    header+= "<th><input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox1' name='mycheckbox1' ></th>";
    header+= "</tr></thead>";
    table += header;
    table+="<tbody>";
    for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr>";
        var row = data[i];
        var cells = row.join(",").split(",");
        if (cells.length < size) continue;
        else if (cells.length > size) size = cells.length;
  if (cells.length > check){
   alert('Data Yang Anda Masukkan Salah');
  }
  else{
        for (j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  var a = 1.000;
       var b = 10.000;
       var c = 20.000;
       var d = 45.000;

       var callback1 = '10.000';
       var callback2 = '20.000';
       var callback3 = '37.500';
       var callback4 = '45.000';
       table += "<td>";
        table += cells[j];
        table += "</td>";
  }
  if (cells[5]> a && cells[5] <b){
   table += "<td>"+ callback1 +"</td>"
  }
  else if (cells[5]> b && cells[5] <c){
   table += "<td>"+ callback2 +"</td>"
  }
  else if (cells[5]> c && cells[5] <d){
   table += "<td>"+ callback3 +"</td>"
  }
  table += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox' name='mycheckbox'></td>"
        table += "</tr>";  
  }
    }
    table+="</tbody>";
    table += "</table>";
    $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
 
}   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.5/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:5px 5px; margin-left:5px">
 <div class="well" style="width:70%">
  <div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="files">Upload File Data :</label>
     <input type="file" id="files"  class="form-control" accept=".csv" required />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-file" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="row" style="width:90%">
   <form action="" id="form_data" name="form_data" method="post">
   <div id="parsed_csv_list" class="panel-body table-responsive" style="width:90%">
   </div>
            </form>
  </div>
```

After I can checked my checkbox I want to make a new `th` column in the last row of the `thead` and in the last row of the each `tbody`.
The value of the column is `Tilting` when it checked and `Borongan` when unchecked.

for the csv file you can download in this link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_zAPPvH-idZZkxSRDI4NGNHOHc

Comment: Your original code snippet is not populating table, fix it please

Comment: i have edited all of my code.. and it working snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is the element you are setting change event to is not present at the time of binding, so you will have to set it on a element which is present. I could give you the answer but that won't help in long run.As I am not a very good at explaining concepts I will just point you to the problem you are having with answer in it -

[jQuery .on('change', function() {} not triggering for dynamically created inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418963/jquery-onchange-function-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-inputs)

For second part research more. (Also I did not understand)