# popup the model on select change option in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a table and inside it I have a select

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($cheques as $key => $cheque)
        <tr data-id="{{ $cheque->id }}">
            <td><a href="#" class="btn-detail-cheque">{{ $cheque->reference }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $cheque->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cheque->owner }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cheque->receiver }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cheque->date_entree->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
            <td>{{ $cheque->date_payment->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
            <td>
                <select name="statue" class="form-control" id="statue">
                    <option value="0" {{ $cheque->statue == "0" ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ __('messages.cheques.waiting') }}</option>
                    <option value="1" {{ $cheque->statue == "1" ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ __('messages.cheques.payed') }}</option>
                    <option value="2" {{ $cheque->statue == "2" ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ __('messages.cheques.not_payed') }}</option>
                    <option value="3" {{ $cheque->statue == "3" ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ __('messages.cheques.transfered') }}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ url('/cheques/edit/'.$cheque->id) }}" class="text-info btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="text-danger btn-remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
         </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

and i want when ever the select statue change i want to pop the model and this is what i done

```
        $("#statue").on('change', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var id = $(tr).data('id');
            var statue = $(this).val();

            bootbox.confirm({
                size: "small",
                message: "{{__('messages.cheques.statue_confirmation')}}",
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label:"{{__('messages.buttons.confirm')}}",
                        className: 'btn-sm btn-danger'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label:"{{__('messages.buttons.cancel')}}",
                        className: 'btn-sm btn-defaul'
                    }

                },
                callback: function(result){
                    if(result){
                        if(statue == 3){
                            $("#transfer-cheque-form").find("#id").val(id);
                            $("#transfer-cheque").modal();
                        }else{
                            $.post('change-statue/'+id, {_token:$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), statue:statue}, function(data){
                                if(data.success){
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

but the problem is the model popup only on the first item on the table otherwise nothing happens

i'm using an template ready who has a dynamic table with pagination

Comment: You need to provide a selector to the on function. Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418963/jquery-onchange-function-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-inputs

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is you are grabbing it by id of statue.  The id is supposed to only correspond with one item on the page (id's should be unique).  What you probably want to do is add a class to your select and modify your jquery selector to select that class instead.

```
<select name="statue" class="form-control" id="statue" class="statue-select">

$(".statue-select").on('change', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks that fixed the problem but only on the first page of the pagination the second on not working

Comment: jQuery is only applying the handler to the elements that exist on the page at the time this code runs.  If you want pagination to work correctly, this needs to be applied each time the pagination is interacted with.  Another, probably simpler solution would be to move everything to a javascript function and set an `onchange` attribute on the select.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly an HTML DOM can only contain single with an ID. You can do  :

```
$('select[name="statue"]').on('change', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

If your elements are getting appended/manipulated dynamically on ajax pagination for example, you can do  :

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="statue"]', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a static ID in the select element, you can solve the problem adding a function to listen the select change

```js
function myFunction(event){
  //TODO
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(event)">
```